# RSelenium Invalid call to server

Tags: r, google-chrome, selenium, rselenium

when I run the introductory code in R,

```
require(RSelenium)
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4444, browserName = "chrome")

remDr$navigate("http://www.google.com")
```

I get the error

> Invalid call to server. Please check you have opened a browser.
>
> Error in queryRD(paste0(serverURL, "/session/", sessionInfo$id, "/url"),  :

sessionInfo() :

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RSelenium_1.3.5 XML_3.98-1.1    RJSONIO_1.3-0   RCurl_1.95-4.5 
[5] bitops_1.0-6   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] caTools_1.17.1 tools_3.1.2
```

Comment: Are you running a selenium server? Try running `RSelenium::startServer()`. You will also need chromeDriver installed `https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads`

Comment: I've run that command with no error.  err, checking for driver now

Comment: I'm on Windows 8.  I've downloaded and extracted chromeDriver.  I've also tried placing it in the same folder as the Chrome application, and in several subfolders, with no success.  Perhaps I am installing chromeDriver incorrectly?  I'm having trouble finding clear directions for Windows 8.

Comment: There is a vignette on driving the various browsers http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/13885_78ec248f224e4893ac2ebb3741d748bd.html#id1a . chromeDriver needs to be in your path in which case Selenium Server should be able to find it.

Comment: I've placed chromedriver in the same directory as the chrome application, and added that directory to my system path through the control panel.  same error occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the line

```
remDr$open()
```

between the remoteDriver assignment and the remDr$navigate() command, in addition to editing the system path, and was able to achieve success.